# Is there a Method on EPPLUS like get_item(index)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, epplus

I want to convert my old code in C# to become a xlsx via EPPlus but i don't find any method like `get_item(index)` for example i can't convert this Code via Epplus:

```
private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet MyWorksheet;
MyWorksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)MyWorkbook.Worksheets.get_Item(index);
```

Comment: As far as I remember there is also a worksheets collection which you can enumerate.

Comment: Where did you find `get_Item` in the first place? Both VB6 and all .NET languages work with indexers. `get_Item` wouldn't even appear as a method in those languages. Did you try to convert some C++ code perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be something like

```
yourExcelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[x]
```

where x starts with 1 (found this here on so)